# What exactly does the verb "fall" mean when it is used for a cake?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "fell" mean in this sentence?

> When my mother tried it [raisin pound cake], the cake **fell** almost every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When baking, the cake or pie may *rise* due to air bubbles expanding due to higher temperature (air expands), sometimes if one is not careful the cake may *fall* (become flat), this may be due to the structure of the cake becoming unstable.  It may also happen if the yeast, which is what makes the air bubbles, is outdated.

It's when you get this

[image]

Instead of this

[image]
<sub>(source: [bbcgoodfood.com](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/chocolate-avocado-cake.jpg))</sub>

Most famous for *falling* are souffles which are very fragile and easily disturbed by changes in temperature or vibrations.